# Update to kernel 4.15.0-51 can't find encrypted drive

Tags: boot, 18.04, updates, encryption

I recently performed a kernel upgrade on my tablet, going from 4.15.0-50 to 4.15.0-51.  On reboot, it dropped to busybox.  The system did not seem to know about my encrypted hard drive -- i.e. it had nothing to do.

Does anyone know if this is a peculiarity of the new kernel, or what might have caused this boot up problem?  I can still boot to 4.15.0-50, so my initial inclination is to wait out 0-51, and hope the problem is fixed in future kernel updates.

Does anyone know if this is a peculiarity of my own system, or perhaps the system update will break anyone's configuration that uses an encrypted hard drive?

Comment: The version is in my question -- see the tags.  It was a regular system upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had searched launchpad and could not find anything related to this problem.  Sometimes it's hard to tell what's a bug and when I might have overlooked something obvious.

Comment: You are welcome. Your commend about whether it is a bug or not is fair. You may want to edit your question and add the information you provided in the comments.